# Why my condition is not work correctly? PHP Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

> NOTE: Before of my view, I have a another view that show all animals and classes of the tables animals and classes. And in that view I have a button that shows more specific details when I click on a specific record.
>
> This is the button that redirect to my view. We will call this view as Animal Details view.

**The ANIMAL DETAILS view.**

I have a condition in my view where is suppose that compare 2 field's values between 2 tables. The table Animals and the table Classes.

This is the condition.

```
<!--TABLE ANIMALS DETAILS IN MY VIEW-->
<!--THEAD-->
<tbody>     
    <tr>
        <td>{{$animal->id}}</td>
        <td>{{$animal->name}}</td>
        <td>{{$animal->area}}</td>
                            
            @if($animal->animal_class_id == $class->id)
                <td>{{$class->name}}</td>
            @endif
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I try to compare the values between **`animal_class_id` (of the table Animals)**, and **`id` (of the table Classes)** and then show the corresponding name of the class.

But **It don't work,** it compare the **`id`** **(of the table Animals)** and the **`animal_class_id`** **(of the table Animals too)**.

Why my condition don't compare the fields that I try to compare?

Also I will put my controller, function **`show()`**

```
public function show($id){

    $animal = AnimalNew::find($id);

    $class = AnimalClass::find($id);

    $habitat = Habitat::all();

    return view('animals.ShowAnimalsDetails',  compact('animal', 'class', 'habitat'));

}
```

Maybe I can do a condition in the function **`show()`** where I can compare the values between the fields: **`animal_class_id`** from the table animals, and **`id`** from the tables Classes.

For example, I have this records:

**TABLE ANIMALS**

```
id|name       | animal_class_id

1 |Lion       | 1
2 |Tiger      | 1
3 |Salamander | 2
4 |Sparrow    | 3
5 |Ant        | 4
```

**AND THE TABLE Classes**

```
id| name

1 | Mammals
2 | Amphibians
3 | Birds
4 | Insects
```

It works only with the first record, where the 2 id, respectively, has the same values. In this case Lion have id = 1 and animal_class_id = 1 too.

But as I said before, I want to compare the values between the fields **`animal_class_id`** of the **table Animals** and the **`id`** of the **table Classes**, not the **`id`** and **`animal_class_id`** of the same table.

Comment: Why not just use a relationship, and you can iterate through that instead?

Comment: @aynber I'm sorry, I don't understand you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your show function, you find $class and $animal by the same id,
but it is not true, you can find $animal by id, and `$class = AnimalClass::where('id', $animal-> animal_class_id)->first();`

But the best way is use oneToMany relactionship: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

In your model file(AnimalClass.php), add:

```
public function animalNews() {
  return $this->hasMany('App\AnimalNews');
}
```

And Your model file(AnimalNew.php), add:

```
public function animalClass() {
  return $this->belongsTo('App\AnimalClass');
}
```

In the view:

```
<!--TABLE ANIMALS DETAILS IN MY VIEW-->
<!--THEAD-->
<tbody>     
  <tr>
    <td>{{$animal->id}}</td>
    <td>{{$animal->name}}</td>
    <td>{{$animal->area}}</td>
    <td>{{$animal->animalClass()->first()->name}}</td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: First, I have already those relationship, Second. Then in my view when I write this I get an error, that says: `Trying to get property 'name' of none-object (C:\xampp\htdocs\zoo\resources\views\Animals\AnimalDetails.blade.php).` And Third, the field `name` should come from the **table Classes**, so I think that I will should call to this field like this, `<td>{{$class->name}}</td>`

Comment: ```$animal->animalClass()``` is a method,I have change my answer.

Comment: I tried this, but I had another error: `Call to undefined method...` in my `AnimalDetails.blade.php` that is my view.

Comment: ```Call to undefined method...``` Please post complete error msg.

Comment: `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::animalClass() (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\zoo\resources\views\Animals\AnimalDetails.blade.php)` That is the error.

Comment: Do you really add ```animalClass()``` in your AnimalNew model?

Comment: I should add this as a public variable, with which value?

Comment: Add this ```public function animalClass() {
  return $this->belongsTo('App\AnimalClass');
}``` in your AnimalNew.php

Comment: No, it's not work yet. And I have already this function on my model AnimalClass()

Comment: No, the function ```animalClass()``` must be on your model AnimalNews, not model AnimalClass,